# Cannot set property 'elements' of undefined - Array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I got the following error with my code.

> "Cannot set property 'elements' of undefined"

Code looks like this:

```js
this.languages.forEach((value, index) => {
  debugger
  this.languageTableElement = { type: 'checkbox'}
  this.languageTableRows[index].elements.push(this.languageTableElement)
})
```

The question is: How to define the `elements`?

Comment: The problem is `this.languageTableRows[index]` is undefined. Not `elements`.

Comment: share code via stackblitz

Comment: You need to show more code. How is `this.languageTableRows` array defined? Is the element `this.languageTableRows[index]` already defined to be an object?

Comment: It's undefined too, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i reconized how to do it, the answer is simple:

```
this.languageTableRows = [];
    
    this.languages = await this.languageService.getAllLanguages().toPromise();

    this.languages.forEach((value, index) => {
      this.languageTableRows[index] = new TableRowModel;
      this.languageTableRows[index].elements = [];
      this.languageTableElement = { type: 'checkbox'}

      this.languageTableRows[index].elements.push(this.languageTableElement)
    })
```